# Getting a white page on IE 10, Firefox and Chrome

Tags: 2007, internet-explorer, firefox

**When trying to open a SharePoint URL on IE 10, Chrome and Firefox, the browser is displaying a white page.** Page is loading correctly on IE 8. Also, this issue is occurring on my machine only. I tried the same on another machine and its loading correctly.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your browsers?

Comment: @DanielZiga: Yes i tried that also, but didnt work.